# mapa hecho con arreglos y clases c++

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa con una nave en el que debe moverse en la pantalla pero debo agregarle un mapa el cual debe ser un cuadro pegado a la izquierda y otro a la derecha y que la nave tenga un espacio para pasar por en medio y debe estar hecho con una clase y arreglo, me esta dando error y estoy algo perdido, requiero su apoyo con alguna explicación, aqui dejo mi código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "windows.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRIBA 72
#define ABAJO 80
#define IZQUIERDA 75
#define DERECHA 77

using namespace std;

int x=37, y=20;

void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    HANDLE hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon,dwPos);
}

class Mapa{
    private:
        int cx, cy;
        int color;
        int arr[40];
    public:
        void MostrarLimite();
        void ArregloMapa();
};

void Mapa::MostrarLimite(){


}

void Mapa::ArregloMapa(){
    int n;
    for(int i=0; i<39; i++){
        gotoxy(i,0); printf("&c",205);
    }
}


void imprimir(){
    gotoxy(x,y); printf("  %c  ",202);
    gotoxy(x,y+1); printf(" %c%c%c ",91,207,93);
    gotoxy(x,y+2); printf("%c%c %c%c",174,206,206,175);
}

void borrar(){
    gotoxy(x,y); cout<<"     ";
    gotoxy(x,y+1); cout<<"     ";
    gotoxy(x,y+2); cout<<"     ";
}

void OcultarCursor(){
    HANDLE hCon;
    hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cci;
    cci.dwSize = 100;
    cci.bVisible = FALSE;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(hCon, &cci);
}

int main()
{
    system("mode con: cols=100 lines=50");
    system("color 0B");

    Mapa mapa1();
    mapa1.ArregloMapa();

    char opc;
    imprimir();
    while(opc!='y'){
    OcultarCursor();
    if(kbhit()){
        char tecla = getch();
        borrar();
        if(tecla == ARRIBA &&y>0) y--;
        if(tecla == ABAJO &&y<47) y++;
        if(tecla == IZQUIERDA &&x>0) x--;
        if(tecla == DERECHA &&x<95) x++;
        imprimir();
    }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Buenas. Podrías especificar qué error te da? También estaría bien contar con algún detalle más para poder ayudarte. Ahora mismo parece que lo que intentas es pintar una fila horizontal de caracteres en el método ArregloMapa, es así?

Comment: "*me esta dando error y estoy algo perdido*" Yo también estoy perdido, porque dices que te da error pero no dices qué error te da.

Comment: se trata de un error de compilación? Un error de enlace? Corrige por favor las directivas de inclusión para al menos evitar un error en el preprocesador

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

Comment: No entiendo mucho de lo que me hablan, no sé mucha teoría, mas que nada lo que se es practico, hace poco que entré a esto de la programación y se muy pocas cosas, el error que tenia ya lo resolví, y es que no sabía que cuando uso un objeto de mi clase no debo poner (), el error estaba en Mapa mapa1(); lo que quiero es que en ArregloMapa van a estar mis arreglos, los cuales van a pintar dos cuadros, uno pegado a la izquierda y otro a la derecha pero no tocan el limite de la consola de arriba ni de abajo y estos mismos van a ser el limite de la nave, vamos el mapa tendrá forma de i mayúscula.

Comment: Tienes que concretar los errores que tienes... no puedes esperar que cojamos tu código y nos dediquemos a trastearlo como si fuese un juguete hasta encontrar los fallos que tu ya has detectado

Comment: @MarcoRamírez `<conio.h>` es una cabecera de [tag:c] no de [tag:c++], además de que su cometido es el mismo que `<stdio>` es decir: manipular la entrada y salida de la consola. Así pues `<conio.h>` **no debe usarse en C++**.

Answer (score 0):

Probé tu código, y tambien me da error, lo solucioné, inicializando la variable **opc** en 0.

```
char opc = 0;
```

También vi que en la función **Mapa::ArregloMapa()** al llamar la función **printf()** usas el '&' y debería ser '%'.

O sea, escribistes:

```
printf("&c",205);
```

Y debería escribir así:

```
printf("%c",205);
```